# How do I give access token to Client's users when building BaaS? Is there an OAuth2 grant for that?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

If I'm building a BaaS (Backend-as-a-Service) type of app, how would I give tokens to the users of my Clients' apps?

My thoughts:

- I'm thinking Authorization grant but that would cause a redirect.
- Users ask for Client to get token for them using client credentials. Not really OAuth2.
- Users ask BaaS directly for token which then asks Client first if it should. Not OAuth2 at all.

I can mark Client's Apps as first-party but that would still need a redirect just to get an authorization code. It would not just prompt for authorization.

Say I would build an SDK for this BaaS that might look like:

```
const app = new ChatBaaS("app-id")
const user = app.connect("id-of-user-of-client")
user.sendMessage()
```

What should happen behind the scene so that the user can interact with the BaaS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** OAuth2 allows custom grant. Just make another one if you are already using it.

What is described in OP is a mix of Client Credentials and Password grant.

Instead of using password (which you don't have), you use the Client's credentials.

---

I finally came up with an elegant solution to this problem.

Like what Trey Griffith said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64329134/10975709):

> the question for you is whether its critical to support OAuth2, or more important to avoid the redirect.

The answer is I really don't care at all if it's OAuth2 or not. I was just thinking if there was a grant for it and if not I'd just go with the other 2 solutions in the OP. Fortunately the answer is **YES**!

While writing my custom solution (#2 in the OP), the more I write the codes the more I see that what I'm writing is very similar to OAuth2 stuff.

Asking the Client to get a token for you, its user, the Client would need to do:

- Client (client credentials) -> BaaS (Client token) -> Client
- Client (token + user id) -> BaaS (User token) -> Client -> User

I thought that looks like the Password grant but just without the password but instead the Client's credentials.

I searched if OAuth2 allows or supports custom grants and it does. Apparently OAuth2 is not limited to:

- Authorization
- Client Credentials
- Password
- Implicit

but instead they are just pre-included common grants.

According to https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/

> The OAuth framework specifies several grant types for different use cases, **as well as a framework for creating new grant types**.

the new grant request now looks like:

```
{
  "grant_type": "client_user",
  "user_id": 123456789,
  "client_id": "abcdefgh",
  "client_secret": "supersecret123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at how similar services like Firebase and Auth0 do this.

Using OAuth2 with a non-private client (whether doing PKCE, Authorization Code, etc) will always result in a redirect. So the question for you is whether its critical to support OAuth2, or more important to avoid the redirect.

You can always support OAuth2 for how the end user logs in, for example with Google or Facebook, but your own identification of a user is not OAuth.

Comment: OAuth2 definitely isn't necessary. I think I was just confused with OAuth itself and implementations of it like the Passport and thinking I might be able to reuse some of its internals. I used service like Pusher before and that required the client to implement an endpoint where it can generate a token for its user. I think that's the way to go.